# RDP to Azure server will not load desktop after accepting Disclaimer, shows blank screen with logo

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, azure, rdp

Yesterday I was made aware that my Azure server had an issue with RDP where the user was unable to get past the disclaimer page. Initially restarting the server fixed this issue until this morning where it has had no effect.

When a user tries to log in via remote desktop, they get the disclaimer, as per usual, however once the disclaimer is accepted it disappears but RDP stays on the same screen and does not progress to the desktop.

It is not a credentials issue. (Non domain, set to never expire). I have tried this using multiple clients, including the native client and 3rd party RDP clients, all with he same result.

[image: Blank Screen]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? This can be caused by a lack of resources (CPU, Memory) not allow the logon to process.

Comment: I have and this has not resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further checks this was narrowed down to a Networking fault with Azure.

We noticed packets being dropped to our AD server. After resizing our AD server which moved it to a new host the problem was resolved.

Comment: How was it narrowed down? What were the exact symptoms found to confirm this as the reason?

Comment: After rebooting the instance, confirming the port was listening (nc -vz 1.1.1.1), ensuring the service was running via WinRM and the user was valid and checking the logs for errors.